# How to resolve "Invalid or missing account ID" problem in Google Tag Manager with test environment ? (>m_auth)

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created a testing environment in GTM under Admin > Environments in order to test my tags on my stagging website before to push them live.

So I created the environment and then, pasted the code as high in the  of the page as possible and same for the code dedicated to the body tag.

But when I go test my setup with tag assistant I have 2 errors and I dont understand these.

**FIRST ONE :**

**Account** **ID**
GTM-XXXXXX>m_auth

**HTML Snippet** <script async= "" src= "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX>m_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>m_preview=env-104>m_cookies_win=x" > </script>

**Optimizations**

Invalid or missing account ID

Of course I have change the ID, XXX is just for the message :)

**SECOND ONE :**

**Account ID**
GTM-XXXXXX>m_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx>m_preview=env-104>m_cookies_win=x
URL
[https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX>m_auth=xxxxxxxxx>m_preview=env-104>m_cookies_win=x](https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXXX%3Em_auth=xxxxxxxxx%3Em_preview=env-104%3Em_cookies_win=x)

**Optimizations**

1. Invalid or missing account ID
2. HTTP response code indicates tag
   failed to fire: Status 404. This could be due to an empty or
   un-published container
3. Non-standard implementation

Please, anyone encountered this situation before ?

Best,
Anneso